# How to modify boolean variable value in java byte code?

Tags: java, hook, decompiling

As i find that some java jar using a `boolean` variable to decide whether output the log, the example is as follow:

```
public final class a {
    private static boolean a = false;
    private static boolean b = false;
    private static Logger c;
    public static void a(String var0, String var1) {
        if(a) {
            var0 = "Log-" + var0;
            if(b && c != null) {
                c.log(Level.INFO, var0 + ": " + var1);
            } else {
                Log.v(var0, var1);
            }
        }
    }
```

the above code is decompiled by Intellij idea. Since:

1. There is no source code, only `jar` file includes `.class` files
2. The code is obfuscated(as you see the member variable is all a, b, c), so can reflection work?

Here i want to modify the member `private static boolean a`,change from `false` to `true` in order to output the log. I try `jclasslib` but i can only get the variables `as org.gjt.jclasslib.structures.FieldInfo` object, i can not find a way to modify its value. Can anyone help?

Second, i write a class that defines a `boolean` variable like:

```
public class BroadcastHook {
    private static boolean testBoolean=true;
```

What confuses me is that whether the `testBoolean` is `true` or `false`, the `testBoolean` `Fields` is same in `Bytecode viewer`, below is the screenshots
[image: the testBoolean Fields structure in Bytecode viewer]

Why can't i find the false value of `testBoolean` in Fields?

Comment: The initial values are assigned in *code*. You need to look at the byte code of the static initializer to see the assignment.

Comment: Yes reflection can work. You just need to use the actual (obfuscated) member name. So static field `a` on class `a`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes, it works, thank you. but using reflection you can just modify the value while running, you can not modify and save the .class file that modified and then replace the original .class file in the jar, right?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Hi, i'm very clear about what you said, there is no the static initializer in a.class file, you mean check the <clinit> Methods in Bytecode viewer?

Comment: Yes, exactly, <clinit>.

Comment: @chou That's true. You can do it at the start of your application though.

Comment: You have decompiled code from IntelliJ. Save that as a new java file, make the changes you need, recompile and repackage into a new jar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the right one but the change is simple:

To change the boolean variable from `true` to `false` hex edit a `0x04` to `0x03`.